# LDA-like algorithm but at the character level?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, unsupervised-learning, pattern-recognition

I have a catalog of products and I'd like to find "topics" in their description. The problem is that you might find in the description things like GraphicsCardVendor10.2 GraphicsCardVendor_10.3 etc. Obviously, for us humans it is simple to unravel the topic "Graphics Cards"

Of course, I can do some preprocessing but I'm looking for a more holistic way to deal with that. I know some algorithms (like RNNs) can work on character-level.

My end-goal is to find patterns in the data. Sort of, points of interest.
Like, "Hey look, I see a lot of graphics cards over here".

I'd like to get your suggestions what should be the right model for this problem.

- Note: The data is currently not labeled.

Comment: For cases like this my first idea would be to simply apply an ad hoc tokenizer which separates the words. You can run LDA with whatever unit instead of words, but at character level it's not going to work very well because a character doesn't convey any meaning.

Comment: @Erwan, The thing is, I would need to constantly maintain this tokenizer, wouldn't I? Instead, models like RNN can do that for me (I guess)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But you'll probably also have to check that the system correctly matches special descriptions anyway, so I'm not sure there's a big advantage with a complex solution.